# Malformed Factor error in melt.data.table

Tags: r, data.table, reshape2, melt

After using `melt` in either `data.table` or `reshape2` I need to manipulate the `variable` column's values, so I need it to be a `character` class.  This if failing because of some **malformed factor** error.

I don't understand what the issue is -- perhaps a bug?

Here's a small subset of my data:

```
dput(eg.dat)

structure(list(qtr = structure(c(2004.75, 2005, 2005.25, 2005.5, 
2005.75, 2006, 2006.25, 2006.5, 2006.75, 2007, 2007.25), class = "yearqtr"), 
ACAIND1INR = c("99.5", "101.2333333333333", "105.4666666666667", 
"108.9333333333333", "113.3", "124.8666666666667", "149.7333333333333", 
"167.5333333333333", "170.5", "175.7", "189.6666666666667"
), ACAIND1INR = c("99.5", "101.4", "105.4", "108.9", "113", 
"125.7", "149.5", "167.4", "170.5", "176.3", "189.4"), ACAIND2INR = c("99.2", 
"101.2", "105.1", "108.5333333333333", "113.1", "125.3333333333333", 
"150.5", "170.0666666666667", "171.4666666666667", "173.7333333333333", 
"184.4333333333333"), ACAIND2INR = c("99.2", "101.6", "105.1", 
"108.4", "112.9", "125.5", "149.4", "169.8", "171.5", "174.2", 
"184.3")), .Names = c("qtr", "ACAIND1INR", "ACAIND1INR", 
"ACAIND2INR", "ACAIND2INR"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -11L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000120788>)


        qtr        ACAIND1INR ACAIND1INR        ACAIND2INR ACAIND2INR
 1: 2004.75              99.5       99.5              99.2       99.2
 2: 2005.00 101.2333333333333      101.4             101.2      101.6
 3: 2005.25 105.4666666666667      105.4             105.1      105.1
 4: 2005.50 108.9333333333333      108.9 108.5333333333333      108.4
 5: 2005.75             113.3        113             113.1      112.9
 6: 2006.00 124.8666666666667      125.7 125.3333333333333      125.5
 7: 2006.25 149.7333333333333      149.5             150.5      149.4
 8: 2006.50 167.5333333333333      167.4 170.0666666666667      169.8
 9: 2006.75             170.5      170.5 171.4666666666667      171.5
10: 2007.00             175.7      176.3 173.7333333333333      174.2
11: 2007.25 189.6666666666667      189.4 184.4333333333333      184.3
```

When I run:

```
melt(eg.dat, id.vars = 'qtr', variable.factor = FALSE)
```

I get the error the factor variable is **malformed**, but I can't figure out what that means or how to fix it:

```
Error in melt.data.table(eg.dat, id.vars = "qtr", variable.factor = FALSE) : 
    malformed factor
```

I've never encountered this before, and I haven't been able to find documentation of this error.

Comment: My guess is that it doesn't like your repetition of col names... hm, no that's not it, since `melt(data.table(id = 1, a = 1, a = 2), id = "id")` works.

Comment: It works fine with reshape2's melt `setDF(eg.dat); melt(eg.dat, id.vars = 'qtr', variable.factor = FALSE)` Since it's meant to reproduce reshape2 behavior, I guess this is a bug. If you think it fits, here are instructions to file a bug report https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Support

Comment: I don't think it's really a bug. Dataframes and by extension data.tables are not supposed to have multiple columns with the same name. There's no error if the columns are named to abode by that rule. I do wish the data.table  print method would enclose character values in quotes, since those values (except for the qtr) are all character values.

Comment: @42- `print(eg.dat, class=TRUE)` released with 1.9.8, I think, part of ongoing tasks here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1523

Comment: @42 Correcting the variable names so that the column names are all unique solved the issue.  I'll accept that if you post it as an answer.  Strange though that `melt` worked with non-unique names for a `factor`-type `variable` but not with the `character` case.  Anyhow, working fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's really a bug. Dataframes and by extension data.tables are not supposed to have multiple columns with the same name. There's no error if the columns are named to abide by that rule. I do wish the `data.table`-print method would enclose character values in quotes, since those values (except for the qtr) are all character values.